# Why do magnets silence anvils?

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics, metals

Today I've been to a forge. The blacksmith demonstrated that if he beats the anvil without a magnet attached, it make horrible noises. As soon as he reattached it, the sound of the anvil was way more pleasant.

The anvil had a weight of 250 kg,  the magnet had the size of a mozzarella.

What is causing this?

Comment: I am no expert, but was it a heavy weight by any chance, might dampen the amplitude of the sounds, maybe nothing to do with magnets.

Comment: I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Still, I think you can tune the vibrations with a relatively small weight. If you go back to the shop, try moving it to different places on the anvil. I am pretty sure any magnetic effect is not the reason.

Comment: How big is a mozzarella?

Comment: Three ideas: 1. if the anvil is attached to a high-quality resonator, the higher the $Q$-factor, the thinner the resonance peak. The extra mass would detune it slightly further off the peak, which could have a disproportionate effect on wave amplitudes. 2. If some overtone is really pronounced due to a geometric reason like symmetry, it's possible that changing the geometry will totally eliminate that overtone. 3. A combination of the last two could mean that a geometric change disproportionately changes an overtone's frequency which might shift it way off a broad resonance peak.

Comment: @DanielSank: adult male fist-sized, usually.

Comment: @ChrisDrost Thanks. I searched the Wikipedia page on the SI syste, the NIST page, and even asked some colleagues and I couldn't find a definition of the $\text{mozz}$ unit. I know that mozzarella is available in smaller chunks and I didn't want to get confused about unit systems lest we crash pizza or something like that.

Comment: @ChrisDrost imo,  you should put that as an answer. When I searched about magnets and anvils, a lot of anecdotal evidence involving magnets (and "hidden powers") came up, so I think since blacksmiths and farriers go back in history so far, a lot of ye olde traditions have been maintained, including the magnet idea.

Comment: Well, I mean, it's hard to convince a blacksmith to let you superglue an equivalent weight to their anvil, which would be the definitive test. Magnets have the virtue of coming off rather cleanly. We could test whether it really due to the magnet somehow increasing and aligning magnetic-domain-sizes by using an electromagnet or solenoid which is kept from ever making direct contact with the anvil, I guess.

Comment: I'd first test the effect with the magnet hidden from the smith's sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researchers at the Ohio State University have shown that heat can be controlled with a magnetic field, and that it should also be possible to affect sound waves with a magnetic field.  Apparently phonons, the quasi-particles associated with compressional waves and vibrations in a lattice, have magnetic properties.  Here is an account of the study: https://news.osu.edu/news/2015/03/23/heatmag/.

Essentially, the vibrations of the thinner parts of an anvil are like heat, the vibration of atoms and molecules.  Acoustic waves are also like heat.  They cause materials to vibrate, and they are produced by vibrating material.

The Ohio State researchers were able to control heat flowing through diamagnetic conventionally non-magnetic material.  The study "said that the magnetic field caused some of the phonons passing through the material to vibrate out of sync so that they bumped into one another…"

I suspect that ferromagnetic material such as an anvil would be particularly susceptible to magnetic damping of internal vibrations, particularly if the magnet is large and placed on the thinner parts of the anvil.

Comment: So could it be that the vibration of the sound waves inside the metal induce eddy currents in the presence of the magnetic field, which dampen the waves faster?

Comment: @fibonatic: Perhaps.  The researchers believe that when a magnetic field is applied, phonons tend to run into each other more frequently, which slows them down and lowers the amount of heat or sound they generate.  Maybe this is caused by induced eddy currents, as you say.  When I think of induction, it's in terms of macroscopic movement, but perhaps vibration can induce electric current in the presence of a stationary magnetic field.  If so, each eddy current would produce a magnetic field opposed to the stationary field, resulting in chaos and collisions among phonons.

Comment: The magnet was so weak and small the blacksmith was able to remove and attach it without tools. On the other hand the anvil was a 250kg block of steel. Isn't the magnet's effect negligible?

Comment: @MaxRied: If applied to a narrow part of the anvil, a small magnet may induce a slightly larger volume of confused phonons, or phonons acting counter to a universal pattern of sound vibrations, which may act as a plug of lead or heavier material to locally damp and maybe break up the ringing of the entire anvil.  I wonder if a fist-sized plug of mass-loaded vinyl or lead packed into a properly shaped void in the anvil at an area prone to vibration might have the same effect?  If so, such an anvil could be advertised and marketed as a quieter anvil.

Comment: The link seems dead now.

Comment: @Urb   Here is a discussion of how a magnetic field can control heat and sound:  https://theconversation.com/magnetic-fields-can-control-heat-and-sound-39154

Comment: @Ernie Nice! Consider perhaps editing your answer to add this link, since this news article appears to be from the same date as the original one, but this works.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, reading up about it, here's what I *think* is happening. Just a guess.

I think when an anvil rings, there are parts of the anvil that vibrate vigorously, and parts that are self-damping. Or perhaps there's a surface standing wave, some areas with nodes and some areas with antinodes. In any case, the vibrations happen in specific areas of the anvil. By putting a magnet in a certain place, you can strategically damp the vibrations.

There's an easy way to test this theory: move the magnet around and see what happens! And if it can be done safely, place your hand on different areas of the anvil, and feel if some areas have stronger vibrations.

Answer (score 3):

[Blacksmith Forum](http://www.bladesmithsforum.com/index.php?showtopic=23941)

This answer is just to illustrate how one blacksmith reduced the noise level without resorting to magnets or weights. Over time, and literally being hammered every day, even a well tied down anvil must loosen it's bolts and  restraining materials and start to vibrate and produce the noise mentioned.

> The more mass involved, the less vibration and noise. Materials that absorb or change the frequency of vibration help also. I am a firm believer in bolting the anvil down tight and putting something in-between the anvil and stand. Many on the forum have had good luck using industrial adhesive or silicone caulk, you know, stuff that comes in a tube and you apply with a caulking gun. A good layer of that on the bottom of the anvil, set it in place, bolt it down good, and voila! I lucked into a roll of some kind of rubber underlayment for cork flooring tiles that some workers were throwing away after a job. It is about 5mm thick. I just cut a piece to the shape of my anvils base and put it in-between before bolting the anvil down. The type of stand that is a big box full of sand with the anvil bolted to a plate setting on top of the sand works pretty well to deaden anvil noise. Just make sure to put a layer of something between the anvil and the plate.

Answer (score 3):

I did an anvil ring noise suppression test using a couple small magnets, and the results were surprising.  I made a YouTube video of it:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAWk3SONnw8

Comment: Welcome to the physics stack exchange! Generally we try to make it so that people don't have to follow links to external sites in order to understand questions or answers here. Would you mind editing your answer so that it contains a description of your experiment and what the results were? If visuals are necessary, it's possible to embed images into questions and answers.